# Keepalived increasing slave/master promotion interval/timeout (advert_int) not working

Tags: linux, high-availability, keepalived

I am trying to increase the default interval (advert_int) which triggers a slave to master promotion which seems to be 1 second by setting it on keepalived.conf to 3 seconds:

```
vrrp_instance VI_1 {
  state MASTER
  #How often to send out VRRP advertisements
  advert_int 3
...
}
```

Testing this setting via stopping keepalived or even shutting down master node I get the same promotion to master interval of 1 second again.
Is there any other setting/parameter that needs to be configured?

Thanks